# Send data-* Attributes with select2 ajax

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery-select2

I have the following code for select2 to load from the server using ajax and it is working fine.

**Javascript Code**

```
$('.MySelect2').select2(
    {
        ajax:
        {
            url: 'https://example.com/Source',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 100,
            Results: function (data, page)
            {
                return {
                    results: data.items
                };
            },
            data: function (params) 
            {
                return {
                    q: params.term, page: params.page, pg: 10
                };
            },
        }
    });
```

**JSON Returne from Server using AJAX**

```
{"results": 
 [{"id": "MyID1","text": "MyText1"},]
,[{"id": "MyID2","text": "MyText2"},]
,[{"id": "MyID3","text": "MyText3"},]
,"pagination": { "more": true } 
}
```

**and the resulted option will be**

```
<option value="MyID1">MyText1</option>
<option value="MyID2">MyText2</option>
<option value="MyID3">MyText3</option>
```

My question is how to add more data-* Attributes in the JSON so I can have something like this result:

```
<option value="MyID1" data-extra-info="x1">MyText1</option>
<option value="MyID2" data-extra-info="x2">MyText2</option>
<option value="MyID3" data-extra-info="x3">MyText3</option>
```

Comment: You can add data-extra-info attribute when you creating each of the options

Comment: These options are created automatically using JSON. So where to put data-extra-info? I have tried to put it in JSON but it doesn't work

Comment: i suggest you toread jqyery-select2 document there are some solutions

Comment: Believe me, select2 documentation is one of worst document ever.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? I have it too , and can not find working solution ..

Answer (score 2):

This issue was giving a huge pain and headache until i was able to find a solution for it and it was satisfying what i need.

First of all, your JSON response should be looking something like this:

```
[
   {"id":"MyID1", "text":"MyText1", "MyData1":"Test1", "MyData2":"Hello World"},
   {"id":"MyID2", "text":"MyText2", "MyData1":"Test2", "MyData2":"Hola Mundo"},
   {"id":"MyID3", "text":"MyText3", "MyData1":"Test3", "MyData2":"Bonjour le monde"}
]
```

After making sure all your additional data attributes are added in that JSON response, your JavaScript should be like this: *(Of course, you can play with it and tweak it as you want)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#YourDropDownID").select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "url",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
           return {
              searchTerm: params.term
           };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
           return {
              results: response
           };
        },
        cache: true
      }
   }).on('change', function(e) {
       document.getElementById("ElementID1").innerHTML = $(this).select2('data')[0].MyData1;
       document.getElementById("ElementID2").innerHTML = $(this).select2('data')[0].MyData2;
   });
});
```

Just to explain breifly what happens here:

```
.on('change', function(e) {
      document.getElementById("ElementID1").innerHTML = $(this).select2('data')[0].MyData1;
      document.getElementById("ElementID2").innerHTML = $(this).select2('data')[0].MyData2;
});
```

When the select2 change event happen, it will get the data from the response, and add it to an element in the page, and of course, you can change the first part to whatever element or value you need `document.getElementById("ElementID1").innerHTML`

Hopefully that would help anyone who need this, because it was very helpful for myself.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. That `$(this).select2('data')[0]` is what I was looking for.